# how to stop the setTimeout recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

I have created the setTimeout which has a callback named run, Inside the run I have called a `console.log(i)` to print the value of I with `i++` and once it reaches to 50, I want to clear the `setTimeout` with `clearTimeout`, I am calling setTimeout again with run making it recursive, but it doesn't work.
can somebody help me understand the concept better?

```
let i = 1;

var abc = setTimeout(function run(){
   console.log(i);
if(i==50){
    abc1();
  }  
  i++;
  setTimeout(run,100);
},100);
function abc1(){
     clearTimeout(abc);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I am assuming it is `run is not defined`?

Comment: As an aside - are you aware of `setInterval` / `clearInterval`? If you know that you want to keep running the same thing repeatedly until a certain condition, they might be a better choice.

Comment: @nightgaunt `run` *is* defined - it's the named function expression passed to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setTimeout` you get the ID of the timer returned. It's exactly what you've done here:

```
var abc = setTimeout(function run(){
```

However, that ID is valid only until the delayed function executes. Once it does, it's ineffective. When you call `setTimeout(run,100);` you will get a *new* ID for the timer. You need to capture that again, otherwise the ID gets lost and you have no way to stop it.

There is a final consideration - with your current code even if you were to correctly capture the ID calling `abc = setTimeout(run, 100);` that would still not stop the counter because it will attempt to stop the function that is running right now (which does nothing), instead of cancelling the execution of the next one:

```
let i = 1;

var abc = setTimeout(function run() {
  console.log(i);
  if (i == 50) {
    abc1(); //this will clear the *current* timer 
  } 
  i++;
  abc = setTimeout(run, 100); //this will set the *new* ID 

}, 100);

function abc1() {
  clearTimeout(abc);
}
```

In order to stop the execution you have two options. If you want to use your initial idea, you need to cancel the future execution *after* it is scheduled

```js
let i = 1;

var abc = setTimeout(function run() {
  console.log(i);
  abc = setTimeout(run, 100); //this will set the *new* ID 
  if (i == 50) {
    abc1(); //this will clear the *new* timer now
  }
  i++;
}, 100);

function abc1() {
  clearTimeout(abc);
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it without using timer handles at all and just use the `if` condition to determine if you want to schedule another execution or not:

```js
let i = 1;

setTimeout(function run() {
  console.log(i);
  if (i != 50) { //until 50 is reached
    abc = setTimeout(run, 100); //schedule a new execution
  }
  i++;
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the order of your operations.

```
if(i==50){
    abc1();
  }
```

If i reaches 50, the function abc1() will be called - which clears the interval.

```
i++;
setTimeout(run,100);
```

here you're restarting the interval.
You need to wrap it inside an else block.

```js
let i = 1;

var abc = setTimeout(function run() {
  console.log(i);
  if (i == 50) {
    abc1();
  } else {
    i++;
    setTimeout(run, 100);
  }
}, 100);

function abc1() {
  clearTimeout(abc);
}
```

Comment: Calling `abc1()` produces new effect in this case. It will only clear a handle for a timer that's already executed. It's superfluous at best, but it really shouldn't be done consciously.

Answer (score 1):

```
let i = 1;

var abc = setTimeout(function run(){
  console.log(i);
  if(i<50){
      setTimeout(run,100);
    }  
  i++;

},100);
```

You should run timeout only if timer not run out.

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout() inside run() in not assigned to any variable so it can't be cleared in any manner.

I suppose what you want is to overwrite abc so you must replace:

```
setTimeout(run,100);
```

by

```
abc = setTimeout(run,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `var abc` is only set once, at the first timeout, you are clearing only the very first Timeout, which very likely is already complete.

`SetTimeout` returns a numeric value, which is an ID to refer to that task. When you call `clearTimeout`, you must inform the ID of the timeout you want to clear, and now you are informing the ID for the very first timeout, which is already finished, thus can't be cleared.

If you wish to clear the last timeout, maybe you would like to always update `abc` with the IDs for each timeout, like this:

```
 abc = setTimeout(run,100);
```

Comment: "*which very likely is already complete*" it's complete by definition. It has to run at least once (the handle that is captured) before it can run another 50 times.

Comment: Not the it matters, but in very a theoretical thought, the ending of each run is not a prerequisite for the execution of the next one. Imagine if there was a `pause()` instruction right after `setTimeout(run,100);`. The execution would theoretically go with no problems (except for 50 instructions paused, but oh well...)

Comment: "*the ending of each run is not a prerequisite for the execution of the next one*" but you delay a function first and you get a handle. Unless something runs `clearTimeout` on that handle, the delayed function executes. If it executes, then running the `clearTimeout` *from the delayed function* means that the handle is already useless - the timer fired. If the timer was cancelled, then the delayed function doesn't run and thus it doesn't call `clearTimeout`. In all cases I can see running cancelling the timer from the delayed function is useless, not *sometimes* useless.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird way of doing a timed loop but you just need to clear (actually not in this case but I like to do it anyway as it is a good practice to release resources once you don't use them anymore) the timeouts (done by keeping track of abc handle) before creating new ones and return after `clear` on the given condition:

```js
let i = 1;

let abc = setTimeout(
  function run(){
    console.log(i);
    if(i==50){
      abc1();
      return;
    }
    abc1();
    i++;
    abc = setTimeout(run,100);
  },
  100
);

function abc1(){
  clearTimeout(abc);
}
```

Comment: hi this code is working fine, can you help me to understand why you called the abc1 two times

Comment: This code works but is not correct. The reason it doesn't continue is because `return` will exit the function before a new one is scheduled - calling `abc1` (and thus `clearTimeout`) is completely superfluous and has no effect on the code. It will only ever clear the handle that is currently running, which is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add return after you call abc1 function. you clear timeout, but then code still running and call setTimeout(run,100) again.

```
        let i = 1;

var abc = setTimeout(function run(){
   console.log(i);
if(i==50){
    abc1();
    return;
  }  
  i++;
  setTimeout(run,100);
},100);
function abc1(){
     clearTimeout(abc);
}
```

Comment: The `return` makes calling `abc1` redundant. Clearing the old handle will not affect anything.